# Don't mix Response.Write with AJAX, but what about UI.HtmlTextWriter?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

[From the blog of the creator of the error message](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx), if you mix Response.Write (among other things) with an UpdatePanel you will likely get PageRequestManagerParserErrorException errors. I was wondering, ***is it ok to mix UI.HtmlTextWriter and UpdatePanels?*** My guess would be that it would not be ok, but I'm not sure. With the limited testing I've done so far, it seems ok. Does anybody know for sure? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlTextWriter is how every control writes its output via the Render method, so, yeah, it's fine. Otherwise no control would render.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest isolating the dynamic response.write code into your code-behind and inject it into a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

In Ra-Ajax we've got a "special stream" which you can write stuff to. Though this "stuff" needs to be JavaScript to be executes back on the client. I am not sure if ASP.NET AJAX have something similar...